# Matching Google Analytics adds to basket between GA and BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to get a count of product adds to basket from my exported Google Analytics data in BigQuery.

When I look in the GA interface, at a particular page, I see 1,669 product adds to basket.

[image]

However, when I try and replicate this on the raw data with the following query, i get 1,322 adds to basket.

```
select date,
SUM(adds) as total_adds
from
(SELECT
    date,
    CONCAT(fullvisitorid, CAST(visitid AS string)) AS session_id,
    hits_product.productlistname as product_list,
    hits_product.productsku as sku,
    CASE WHEN hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS adds
    FROM
    `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20191208` AS t,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
    UNNEST(hits.product) AS hits_product
  WHERE hits_product.productlistname = 'my_page_url'
  and hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '3'
)
    group by 1
```

When I run a similar query for product views the numbers match, so why am I seeing a difference with products adds to basket?

If I ignore the page (by removing `WHERE hits_product.productlistname = 'my_page_url'` from the query above) and run numbers for a full day, I get a perfect match.

I have also tried running unsampled numbers from GA and I still see a difference.